# Displaying data in a leaderboard - Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following model:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
  donations = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  requests = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

I want to get the top 5 users with the most points and display them in an HTML leaderboard template.

Please help

EDIT:

MY VIEW:

```
def leaderboard(request,):
    User.objects.alias(
    total_points=Sum('userdetail__points')
    ).order_by('-total_points')[:5]

    return render(request, 'leaderboard.html')
```

Comment: What if a user has *multiple* `UserDetail`s?

Comment: A user can only have one UserDetail associated with their profile, and that model is constantly being updated with data

Comment: then you better use a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`. It might perhaps even make more sense to add these fields to a (custom) user model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.annotate(
    total_points=Sum('userdetail__points')
).order_by('-total_points')[:5]
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating this both as column and in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.alias(
    total_points=Sum('userdetail__points')
).order_by('-total_points')[:5]
```

Regardless which of the two you pick, you pass these to the context in the template:

```
def leaderboard(request,):
    leaders = User.objects.alias(
        total_points=Sum('userdetail__points')
    ).order_by('-total_points')[:5]

    return render(request, 'leaderboard.html', {'leaders': leaders})
```

and in the template you can render the leaderbord with:

```
{% for leader in leaders %}
    {{ leader.username }}
{% endfor %}}
```

If you want to add the points next to the username, you should work with the `.annotate(…)` variant. You can then render this with:

```
<table>
  <th><td>User</td><td>Points</td></th>
{% for leader in leaders %}
    <tr><td>{{ leader.username }}</td><td>{{ leader.total_points }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is the code you gave me 2 different approaches?

Comment: @bannannaqolalal: yes, the latter can be used since [tag:Django-3.2], and is slightly more efficient than the former.

Comment: Thank you so I used the latter, and I now have a view built up. How do I pass the values in to my HTML?

Comment: I updated my question to include the view

Comment: @bannannaqolalal: through the context, and then in the template you enumerate over the context.

Comment: Thank you, but when I run the code, I get the following error: `AttributeError at /leaderboard/
'UserManager' object has no attribute 'alias'`

Comment: @bannannaqolalal: then likely you are not working with Django-3.2, but with a previous version, and thus then you use `.annotate(..)`.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am getting this error: `NameError at /leaderboard/
name 'leaders' is not defined
`

Comment: @bannannaqolalal: you need to assign the `QuerySet` to a variable `leaders = ...`. See edited answer.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, can you please post the complete view using the annotate method?

Comment: @bannannaqolalal: just use the last code fragment of the view, with `.annotate(..)` iso `.alias(..)`.